# Sharing a LAN printer over a subnet [Gnome-Shell]

Tags: networking, gnome-shell, dd-wrt

Two scenarios for you:

1. `ROUTER1  /        \ /          \ PRINTER        DESKTOP1 [96.96.96.10]  [96.96.96.11]`
2. `ROUTER1 /        \ /          \ PRINTER         ROUTER2 [96.96.96.10]  [96.96.96.11] [192.168.1.1] /     \ /       \ DESKTOP1        DESKTOP2 [192.168.1.11]      [192.168.1.12]`

**My problem**

- In scenario 1, `DESKTOP1` can completely connect to `PRINTER`.
- In scenario 2, `DESKTOP1` cannot connect to `PRINTER`. Why?

I'm assuming the problem has something to do with the configuration of `ROUTER2`. Seems like a simple problem, but am drawing a blank.

Appreciate any advice?

Traceroute info from Desktop1:

```
traceroute to 96.96.96.10 (96.96.96.10), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  DD-WRT (192.168.1.1)  0.597 ms  1.151 ms  1.353 ms
 2  PRINTER (96.96.96.10)  5.102 ms  5.103 ms  5.152 ms
```

ROUTER2 info:

```
Local IP: 192.168.1.1
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 0.0.0.0
Local DNS: 0.0.0.0
DHCP Type: Server    <--- I want to keep this
DNSMasq for DHCP: Yes
DNSMasq for DNS: Yes
DHCP-Authoritative: Yes
```

Comment: On desktop1, how far does `traceroute 96.96.96.10` get?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I'm at home now, will check tomorrow --- just a quick question, is the problem likely to do with port forwarding? i.e. I just need to configure router2 to pass a given address:port from router1 and host it from router1 using some chosen port?

Comment: Port forwarding on router2 would likely only be needed if the printer needs to connect to desktop1, for example, for scanning to a shared folder. It ought not be needed if you just want desktop1 to connect to the printer. But you could help us by posting the config for router2.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - okay I've added traceroute and router2 config

Comment: traceroute indicates desktop1 can reach the printer. What symptoms do you see when you try to print?

Comment: Well I can't even try. I'm using gnome3-shells' "Add Printer" dialog but when it searches for a network printer (presumeably only on the subnet), it comes up with nothing.

Comment: OK, you may want to add to your question that your specific problem is that in GNOME, you can't successfully search for a network printer that is not on your subnet.

Comment: Will do - so it's just the application that's failing, nothing wrong with my setup?

Comment: I don't know if that application can automatically find printers on an adjacent subnet. It would be a good question to ask. Include your printer model, too.  I know Windows 8 can find my HP printer on an adjacent subnet, but I haven't traced things to see what protocol is used.